# SISS is being a big brother and not letting me cast a varchar(23) to a numeric(23,0) in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is using an "OLE DB Command" object to call a stored procedure.

All my datatypes are strings.

Everything works perfectly when I use a placeholder stored procedure that simply takes the inputs from SSIS and inserts the parimiters into a work table.

However, when I added all my logic SSIS started to complain.

I realized that SSIS does not like the fact that I have converted a varchar(23) variable to a numeric(23,0) variable. Why SSIS cares I don't know.

I can call my stored procecedure directly and everything works fine.

However, SSIS is has a problem with this for some reason.

The stored procedure input is this:

```
 @MobilePhoneNumber                           varchar(23)     = null
```

The cast looks like this:

```
select @MobilePhoneNumberNumeric = cast(@MobilePhoneNumber as numeric(23,0))
```

Once I add this cast statement SSIS starts giving me this error message:

"Error converting data type varchar to numeric"

Keep in mind that this stored procedure works if I call it directly.

What can I do to make SSIS happy?

Thanks

Comment: is it possible that you have non numeric data somewhere. Try using `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CAST` like so: `SELECT @MobilePhoneNumberNumeric=TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(23,0),@MobilePhoneNumber)`

Comment: I'm in test mode and the data is numeric. I'm using try catch in the stored procedure to handle errors.

Comment: what is @MobilePhoneNumberNumeric declared as? Also why do you need 23 digits for a phone-number  when I don't think it could get past 15 with country code.

Comment: How often do you add two mobile phone numbers together? Or multiply them? Or apply *any* mathematical operation upon them? Mobile phone numbers are a sequence of numeral **characters**. There shouldn't ever be a reason for them to end up in a column/variable with a numeric datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out... Ok Ok my co-worker Gary had the answer.

The issue is realted to the OLE DB Connection and the provider.

When you establish a new OLE DB Connection you have the opportunity to select the provider.

In the OLE DB Connection the provider selected was:

Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native CLient 10.0

The provider I needed to use is:

Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

Once I made this switch all is good with the world.

Thanks Gary for helping me.

Now let me go see what is on Hacker News :-)